# itext multiline text in bounding box

Tags: java, text, position, itext, multiline

Does anyone know, how to, in iText, add multiline text in bounding box (with coordinates specified).

I tried

```
cb.showTextAligned(
    PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT,
    text,
    bounds.getLeft(),
    TOTAL_HEIGHT-bounds.getTop(),
    0 );
```

But it does not support newlines.
I also tried

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
cb.moveText(300,400);
document.add(new Paragraph("TEST paragraph\nNewline"));
```

This supports newlines but does not react to moveText, so I don't know how to put it at given position or better: bounding box.

I suspect chunks or PdfTemplate or maybe table might help, but i don't (yet) know how to put it together. TIA for help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
Phrase myText = new Phrase("TEST paragraph\nAfter Newline");
ct.setSimpleColumn(myText, 34, 750, 580, 317, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
ct.go();
```

parameters of SetSimpleColumn are:

1. the phrase
2. the lower left x corner (left)
3. the lower left y corner (bottom)
4. the upper right x corner (right)
5. the upper right y corner (top)
6. line height (leading)
7. alignment.

Comment: Thanks. I actually wrote a mini-library for layouts and auto-fitting and tables, which incorporates things you have written in your response.

Comment: What does the box width, box height mean?

Comment: 4. is upper right x corner, 5. is upper right y corner: http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188064/iText-Generate-PDFs-in-Java

Comment: how do you get this text to go ontop of other elements?  It's being hidden behind a table right now.

Answer (score 2):

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(content);
ct.setSimpleColumn(
    new Phrase("Very Long Text"),
    left=20, bottom=100, right=500, top=500,
    fontSize=18, Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
ct.go(); // for drawing
```